# Dont enable jquery dialog button after it is disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a code like this. The dialog opens and works well the first time, and dialog button appears hidden. When the conditions are true, the code enables the button well. After close dialog, when the second time it opens, again it appears hidden correctly, but when it takes the same conditions, it not enable. I put an alert there, and it apperas well, but the sentence  $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Aceptar')").button("enable"); dont works this time. What happens?

Here is a fragment of the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $( "#pregunta3 label" ).click(
    function(event) 
    {
       var eleccion = $(this).text();
       var titulo = $("#h33").text();
       if(event.target==this){


     $("#contiene_preguntas").accordion({active:false});
     $("#pipa3").text(eleccion);

     if($("#pregunta1").length & $("#pregunta2").length)
     {
       if($("#pregunta1 input[type=radio]").is(':checked') & $("#pregunta2 input[type=radio]").is(':checked'))
       {
         var isDisabled = $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled" );

           alert(isDisabled);
           **$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Aceptar')").button("enable")****;

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var isDisabled = $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled" );

     alert(isDisabled);
     $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Aceptar')").button("enable");
```

Why do you have different selectors ?

Are you sure your second selector is the right one ?

Check `console.log( $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Aceptar')") )`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line:

```
var isDisabled = $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled" );
```

it seems to be copied from the jQuery UI example of the option get of the [`button`](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-option).

I don't think you have this selector, so you can want to get the state od the `dialog` or the state of the `button` (I think the second).

Following the code to get them:

- Dialog: `$(<your dialog selector>).dialog( "option", "disabled" );`
- Dialog button: `$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane
  button:contains('Aceptar')").button( "option", "disabled" );`